# Parsing socket.getaddrinfo() in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

In using `socket.getaddrinfo()`:

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("example.net", 8000, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
[(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('93.184.216.34', 8000))]
```

The result is in the form of:

```
(family, type, proto, canonname, sockaddr)
```

I know that `family = AF_INET`, `type = SOCKET_STREAM`, and `sockaddr=(HOST, PORT)`

What does the `proto` and `canonname` mean? What is the "6" in the above return result, and when is `canonname` not empty?

Comment: 6 means TCP. See [IANA Assigned Protocol Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml).

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo): "*`canonname` will be a string representing the canonical name of the host if `AI_CANONNAME` is part of the `flags` argument; else `canonname` will be empty.*"